# You might want an anti-emetic

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

I'm the grumpy old troll who lives under the bridge. If you wanna come over, all you have to do is this. All you have to do is this:

Solve my riddle -

> They call my Mr. 325,
>
> Don't leave your shoes untied.
>
> You might want an anti-emetic,
>
> You also might want to have an EpiPen handy.
>
> I am not something you put your cup down on,
>
> I wood get to the point, but I don't want you to shriek.

HINT:

> The grumpy old troll intro does have something to do with this riddle!

Comment: Might a knowledge tag be appropriate? Answer is pretty specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED as per OP response:**

Are you the:

> *Fury 325* Roller Coaster?

They call my Mr. 325,

> *Fury 325* is a well known coaster

Don't leave your shoes untied.

> You can lose your shoes on coasters

You might want an anti-emetic,

> Known to make people vomit

You also might want to have an EpiPen handy.

> The coaster is hornet/wasp themed, and people often need epiPens for stings?

I am not something you put your cup down on,

> Not to be confused with a 'coaster' for drinks

I wood get to the point

> Wooden Coasters

But I don't want you to shriek.

> People are known to scream on coasters

I'm the grumpy old troll who lives under the bridge.

> I know, at the least, that this could be a reference to Dora the Explorer character who asks riddles.  I don't know how it ties into Roller Coasters

Comment: You pretty much solved it! Your second answer is actually the main answer though and you still have to connect the puzzle to the intro and the "I wood get to the point" line. Once you edit it, I can accept your answer! :)

Comment: Edited.  But I don't get the connection to wood that you wanted as opposed to the one I listed.

Comment: It was a bit tricky, but the wood referred to the Cedar Point park that the Fury is located in and the rollercoaster travels under a bridge. :)

Comment: Ah, Ceder Point, that makes sense.  Thanks!